# Best Way to Present This Data in a Table using Pandas CSV

Tags: python-3.x, excel, pandas, dataframe, datatable

I am trying to find the best, clearest way to represent this exported data highlighted, showing what Percentage of Date Entries are in another Column. The imported file would be the one in the image.

How could I put this in to a table?

I'm using Python to export the data in to a text file for now but it's ugly. Planning on using Pandas to export as a csv.

Only need percentage in the table shown, not the "Matched Dates"

```
70.0% of System A's Entries match System B

Matched Dates:
03/12/2018 04:05
03/12/2018 12:15
09/12/2018 16:20
13/12/2018 20:25
17/12/2018 08:10
17/12/2018 12:15
20/12/2018 20:25



90.0% of System A's Entries match System C

Matched Dates:
03/12/2018 04:05
03/12/2018 12:15
09/12/2018 16:20
13/12/2018 20:25
17/12/2018 08:10
17/12/2018 12:15
20/12/2018 20:25
28/12/2018 16:20
29/12/2018 12:15



70.0% of System A's Entries match System D

Matched Dates:
03/12/2018 04:05
03/12/2018 12:15
09/12/2018 16:20
13/12/2018 20:25
17/12/2018 08:10
17/12/2018 12:15
20/12/2018 20:25



50.0% of System A's Entries match System E

Matched Dates:
03/12/2018 04:05
03/12/2018 12:15
09/12/2018 16:20
13/12/2018 20:25
17/12/2018 08:10



---


System B:

87.5% of System B's Entries match System A

Matched Dates:
03/12/2018 04:05
03/12/2018 12:15
09/12/2018 16:20
13/12/2018 20:25
17/12/2018 08:10
17/12/2018 12:15
20/12/2018 20:25



87.5% of System B's Entries match System C

Matched Dates:
03/12/2018 04:05
03/12/2018 12:15
09/12/2018 16:20
13/12/2018 20:25
17/12/2018 08:10
17/12/2018 12:15
20/12/2018 20:25



87.5% of System B's Entries match System D

Matched Dates:
03/12/2018 04:05
03/12/2018 12:15
09/12/2018 16:20
13/12/2018 20:25
17/12/2018 08:10
17/12/2018 12:15
20/12/2018 20:25



62.5% of System B's Entries match System E

Matched Dates:
03/12/2018 04:05
03/12/2018 12:15
09/12/2018 16:20
13/12/2018 20:25
17/12/2018 08:10



---


System C:

90.0% of System C's Entries match System A

Matched Dates:
03/12/2018 04:05
03/12/2018 12:15
09/12/2018 16:20
13/12/2018 20:25
17/12/2018 08:10
17/12/2018 12:15
20/12/2018 20:25
28/12/2018 16:20
29/12/2018 12:15



70.0% of System C's Entries match System B

Matched Dates:
03/12/2018 04:05
03/12/2018 12:15
09/12/2018 16:20
13/12/2018 20:25
17/12/2018 08:10
17/12/2018 12:15
20/12/2018 20:25



80.0% of System C's Entries match System D

Matched Dates:
03/12/2018 04:05
03/12/2018 12:15
09/12/2018 16:20
10/12/2018 04:05
13/12/2018 20:25
17/12/2018 08:10
17/12/2018 12:15
20/12/2018 20:25



60.0% of System C's Entries match System E

Matched Dates:
03/12/2018 04:05
03/12/2018 12:15
09/12/2018 16:20
10/12/2018 04:05
13/12/2018 20:25
17/12/2018 08:10



---


System D:

87.5% of System D's Entries match System A

Matched Dates:
03/12/2018 04:05
03/12/2018 12:15
09/12/2018 16:20
13/12/2018 20:25
17/12/2018 08:10
17/12/2018 12:15
20/12/2018 20:25



87.5% of System D's Entries match System B

Matched Dates:
03/12/2018 04:05
03/12/2018 12:15
09/12/2018 16:20
13/12/2018 20:25
17/12/2018 08:10
17/12/2018 12:15
20/12/2018 20:25



100.0% of System D's Entries match System C

Matched Dates:
03/12/2018 04:05
03/12/2018 12:15
09/12/2018 16:20
10/12/2018 04:05
13/12/2018 20:25
17/12/2018 08:10
17/12/2018 12:15
20/12/2018 20:25



75.0% of System D's Entries match System E

Matched Dates:
03/12/2018 04:05
03/12/2018 12:15
09/12/2018 16:20
10/12/2018 04:05
13/12/2018 20:25
17/12/2018 08:10



---


System E:

83.33% of System E's Entries match System A

Matched Dates:
03/12/2018 04:05
03/12/2018 12:15
09/12/2018 16:20
13/12/2018 20:25
17/12/2018 08:10



83.33% of System E's Entries match System B

Matched Dates:
03/12/2018 04:05
03/12/2018 12:15
09/12/2018 16:20
13/12/2018 20:25
17/12/2018 08:10



100.0% of System E's Entries match System C

Matched Dates:
03/12/2018 04:05
03/12/2018 12:15
09/12/2018 16:20
10/12/2018 04:05
13/12/2018 20:25
17/12/2018 08:10



100.0% of System E's Entries match System D

Matched Dates:
03/12/2018 04:05
03/12/2018 12:15
09/12/2018 16:20
10/12/2018 04:05
13/12/2018 20:25
17/12/2018 08:10
```

[importData](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PY3MA.png)

Comment: where does come from this data (what file type)? and what is your code so far? where are you stuck in code?

Comment: I'm not really stuck in my code as such.. This is more of a subjective question. Just wondering how I could represent this data in a table. Stupid question I know